How do I find the min and max of a value of one column in postgresSQL and have it return only 2 rows?
I'm using postgresSQL and would like to find the minimum value and the maximum value in one column.  I have to have a column titled Order ID, Minimum Order, Maximum Order in the query.  See the below code for what I have come up with. I want to return only 2 rows. Currently it is returning 2000 rows which is the entirety of the table.
SELECT ord_id AS Order_ID
,min (order_tot) AS Minimum_Order
,max(order_tot) AS Maximum_Order
FROM orders
GROUP BY Order_ID
ORDER BY minimum_order;'


It is doing exactly what you asked which is finding all the Order_ID's  of which there are 2000. In addition it is providing the min and max for order_tot over the entire dataset. If you want just the min and max don't include ord_id AS Order_ID.  If you want something else, like say the order with lowest order_tot and the order with the highest order_tot, then you will need to be more specific in your question.

with highest_order as(
    select max(od.order_total) as Maximum_Order from orders od
),
lowest_order as(
    select min(od.order_total) as Minimum_Order from orders od
)
select * from highest_order
join lowest_order on true 


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Note that if the order_tot are unique (unlikely, right?) then it is easy to get one Order_ID for the minimum and another for the maximum. However, assuming that the totals are not unique, you won't just get two rows, although you can limit the number of rows.
First, we cam look at a SELECT returning the minimum and maximum values:
SELECT MIN(order_tot) AS min
  FROM orders;

SELECT MAX(order_tot) AS max
  FROM orders;

These do not give you the corresponding order identifier, so we have to use a sub-query for that purpose:
SELECT Order_ID,
       order_tot AS Minimum_Order
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_tot = (SELECT MIN(order_tot) FROM orders);

SELECT Order_ID,
       order_tot AS Maximum_Order
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_tot = (SELECT MAX(order_tot) FROM orders);

You may use the LIMIT 1 in order to only grab the first order with that minimum and the first order with that maximum. Just know that with time that "first order" changes in PostgreSQL as you use UPDATE or DELETE+INSERT. To make sure you get the same order each time (until deleted), you would have to sort those orders, somehow. Maybe by Order_ID
... ORDER BY Order_ID LIMIT 1;

If you really want both results in the a single SQL command, you can use the UNION keyword. That's probably not that useful and makes the SQL more complicated than getting the minimum in one query and then the maximum in another. However, if you are creating a VIEW, it can useful to know about that keyword.
So it would become something like this:
    SELECT Order_ID,
           order_tot AS Minimum_Order
      FROM orders
     WHERE order_tot = (SELECT MIN(order_tot) FROM orders);
  ORDER BY Order_ID
     LIMIT 1
UNION
    SELECT Order_ID,
           order_tot AS Maximum_Order
      FROM orders
     WHERE order_tot = (SELECT MAX(order_tot) FROM orders)
  ORDER BY Order_ID
     LIMIT 1;


It would be a lot simpler with ORDER BY order_tot ASC  and ORDER BY order_tot DESC and LIMIT 1 then you could eliminate the MIN() and MAX() sub-queries and the WHERE.

The problem with the ORDER BY order_tot is that the Order_ID will vary for the exact same numbers, if the orders are updated. This is because Postgres does not guarantee a stable order between items with the same value. On the other hand, MySQL is much more likely to keep the order stable. So it depends on whether you want to get the same Order_ID over time or not.


The OP has not made it clear what they want from the query, so it is premature to assign a given outcome. 2) From here MySQL LIMIT Query Optimization: If multiple rows have identical values in the ORDER BY columns, the server is free to return those rows in any order, and may do so differently depending on the overall execution plan. In other words, the sort order of those rows is nondeterministic with respect to the nonordered columns.

